# Why engines are useful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to know the followings:

1. Why engines are useful?
2. What would\could an engine serve?
3. Is it a common practice to use engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at this http://rubyx.com/2011/03/01/start-your-engines it's a simple article by the major contributor to rails engines.

Answer (score 0):

Think about engines like you could think about Legos.

Thanks to them you can create independent Rails app (controllers, models, views, migrations).

You can plug them as you need and feel: very flexible, elegant and useful.